# Save battery by not drawing on every render call

Tags: android, graphics, libgdx

I think there must be an easy solution to this that I'm overlooking. I think one option would be a [FrameBuffer](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/glutils/FrameBuffer.html) but not sure if is the best.

I'm working on a puzzle game which requires intensive calculations when drawn. I've done as much as I can to do as little calculations as possible while updating the screen, but some of them I can't, or would be cumbersome to get rid of. On the other hand, most of the time the user will be looking at the screen while trying to figure out the next move, and the screen will be showing a still image. So running the render code 60 times per second is just a waste of battery.

What would be the easiest way to prevent drawing while there are no changes in the model? Is there any way to tell libGDX to temporarily stop calling render while displaying the last rendered image, or to have some kind of virtual screen in which I can draw and then draw this to the screen?

As I said, I know the FrameBuffer, but it seems like this object is meant to be used for way more complex stuff than what I'm trying to achieve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use non-continuous rendering to only render on demand. There are detailed instructions [here in the documentation.](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Continuous-&-non-continuous-rendering)

The most basic thing to do is put this in `onCreate()`

```
Gdx.graphics.setContinuousRendering(false);
Gdx.graphics.requestRendering();
```

And then in your code, call `requestRendering()` whenever a new frame is needed (such as in response to user input, or continuously when animations are taking place).

Whenever an input action takes place, `Gdx.graphics.requestRendering()` is called once on your behalf, so your input processors and whatnot get a stab at it. And if they do anything in response to the input, they should also call it.